# CodeIgniter Image won't work in Project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a piece of code in a file called tester.php that is in my root folder, and one copy of it in a CI view file. The file tester.php in root folder works as it should, but the code in the view ( or model, controller , no matter where in the acual CI) wont work.

using CI 2.2.0

why is this?

result on the root tester.php:

[image]

result in CI:

[image]

full code:

```
$imageurl = "http://www.example.net/images/images/ABImage_clock_4.jpg";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imageurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$im = imagecreatefromstring ($data);

$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, rand(1,255), rand(1,255), rand(1,255));
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// output text.
$font = 'arial.ttf';

for ($i = 0; $i < 70; $i++) {
    imagesetthickness($im, rand(1, 3));
    $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, rand(1,255), rand(1,255), rand(1,255));

    imagearc(
        $im,rand(1, 300), // x-coordinate of the center.
        rand(1, 300), // y-coordinate of the center.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc width.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc height.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc start angle, in degrees.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc end angle, in degrees.
        $bg // A color identifier.
    );
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

**UPDATE**

There is no errors, and the imageurl does work, so its not the image link.

**THE ISSUE:**
when calling the tester.php from the root folder, it works perfect: [image]

but when using the same code in a controller, view or model, it only produces [image]

**UPDATE 2:**

Controller:

```
class antibot_interface_controller extends CI_Controller {



    function getImage() {
        $this->load->view('tester');
    }


}
```

View:

```
    <?


$imageurl = "http://www.textbasedmafiagame.com/images/images/ABImage_clock_4.jpg";



$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $imageurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$im = imagecreatefromstring ($data);

$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, rand(1,255), rand(1,255), rand(1,255));
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// set background colour.

// output text.
$font = 'arial.ttf';
// imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 10, 55, $color, $font, 'ABCD');

for ($i = 0; $i < 70; $i++) {
    imagesetthickness($im, rand(1, 3));
    $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, rand(1,255), rand(1,255), rand(1,255));



    imagearc(
        $im,rand(1, 300), // x-coordinate of the center.
        rand(1, 300), // y-coordinate of the center.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc width.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc height.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc start angle, in degrees.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc end angle, in degrees.

        $bg // A color identifier.
    );
}


header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

route:

```
$route['antibot/antibot_image'] = "antibot/antibot_interface_controller/getImage";
```

**EDIT3:**

I tried to remove files to check if its not working. but as far i can see it is:

$autoload['model'] = array('cartheft/garage_model');

when that model is there, the image is not showing.
when i remove that model, it will work fine.

the garage_model file:

```
<?



class Garage_model extends CI_model {




}
```

Comment: show your code inside CI.

Comment: Anything in your error log?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju same code.

Comment: @user2959229 no errors :/

Comment: I managed to successfully run your code by creating a simple controller containing `$this->load->view('imagetest');`, where `imagetest.php` was a view containing your exact code (except for the source image url). Is your `$imageurl` correct?

Comment: yes. the imageurl is working as it should on the root tester. have no idea why this is occuring.

Comment: I tried to use the code in a controller, model and view, none of them works as it should ( for testing purposes only).

Comment: i have also tested to take a dump of the $data, and it shows output.

Comment: What is url written in browser's bottom left when you mouse hover mouse broken image?

Comment: Can you try `site_url('images/images/ABImage_clock_4.jpg'); ` instead of `http://www.example.net/images/images/ABImage_clock_4.jpg`?

Comment: @Tpojka what do you mean by that?

Comment: @DenizB that wont work.

Comment: I misunderstood something, sorry. Is php_curl extension enabled on server?

Comment: yes . it is. It is working on the tester.php that is located in the server web root. so its nothing there that fails. @Tpojka

Comment: What is in the browser console?

Comment: Just used your exact code on fresh CI installation and it works lika a charm. Issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @Tpojka would you like me to upload the project?

Comment: I am just telling that code provided in your question is working perfectly in fresh CI installation. Can you confirm that too?

Comment: I will try that tomorrow! sems very weird.

http://www.textbasedmafiagame.com/antibot/antibot_interface_controller/getImage

@Tpojka

Comment: The Content-Type header name is written with an uppercase T. I am not sure if that is the issue

Comment: is: 
$im = imagecreatefromstring ($data);

echo var_dump($im);

result: resource(55) of type (gd) normal?

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi no difference im afraid.

Comment: @maria which browser are you using does problem is on all browsers??
you have content type png be sure you are uploading png image not jpeg/gif image

Comment: google chrome.

but @AnmolRaghuvanshi remember that the code in the root , works. but within the CI dont work.

Comment: @maria what do mean by that "code in root is working" but not in CI??

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi edited thread there now.

the results work good when calling tester.php, but not in the CI, then the image wont work.

Comment: @maria did you have error reporting 'on' in CI??

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi all the error reporting in CI is enabled and there is no errors.

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi updated with more code.

Comment: If PHP spits out any error messages, that will lead to the “broken image” icon you see in the browser – but you won’t see them, because the browser can not display them “as” an image. Look at what data the server returns for the image URL in your browser’s network panel – you should be able to see any potential error messages there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demonstrates one possible way to do this using a typical MVC file pattern using Codeigniter. (Tested with Codeigniter 3.0.2 and PHP 5.6.14)

The following 'controller' is at root/application/controllers/imagetest.php

```
if(!defined('BASEPATH')){ exit('No direct script access allowed'); }

class Imagetest extends CI_Controller
{
  private $imageurl;
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    //Using an actual image I know exists
    $this->imageurl = "http://www.rapidsriders.org/images/PAC_logos/ACA_PAC_blue_sm.jpg";
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->imageurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);

    $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, rand(1, 255), rand(1, 255), rand(1, 255));
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

    // output text.
    $font = 'arial.ttf';

    for($i = 0; $i < 70; $i++)
    {
      imagesetthickness($im, rand(1, 3));
      $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, rand(1, 255), rand(1, 255), rand(1, 255));

      imagearc(
        $im, rand(1, 300), // x-coordinate of the center.
        rand(1, 300), // y-coordinate of the center.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc width.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc height.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc start angle, in degrees.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc end angle, in degrees.
        $bg // A color identifier.
      );
    }
    //pass the image resource to the view file 
    $image['im']= $im;
    $this->load->view('imageview', $image);
  }

}
```

This 'view' file is at root/application/views/imageview.php

```
<?php
//Because Codeigniter uses output buffering when you load a view file
//and because the GD functions are sensitive to the buffer state 
//we need to make sure the output buffer is clear. 
//Otherwise imagepng() will probably fail.
ob_clean(); 
//note use of Codeigniter output class to set header.
$this->output->set_content_type('image/png');
//This would work too, but why not utilize Codeigniter's libraries
//header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Run this with `yourURL/imagetest`

**PLAN B:**

Is a revision on my first answer. 
I added some error checking and abandoned the use of a "view" for the moment.
I'm pretty sure the problem is related to output buffering so be sure to keep the line `ob_clean();` just before the header is sent. I consistently get the missing image placeholder if this is omitted.

Use this code for a new version of **imagetest.php**

```
if(!defined('BASEPATH')){
  exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class Imagetest extends CI_Controller
{
  private $imageurl;

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->imageurl = "http://www.textbasedmafiagame.com/images/images/ABImage_clock_4.jpg";
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->imageurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if($data === FALSE){
      exit('Curl error: '.curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);// or die('bad url:'.$this->imageurl);

    if ($im !== false) {
      for($i = 0; $i < 70; $i++){
        imagesetthickness($im, rand(1, 3));
        $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, rand(1, 255), rand(1, 255), rand(1, 255));

        imagearc(
          $im, rand(1, 300), rand(1, 300), rand(1, 300), 
          rand(1, 300), rand(1, 300), rand(1, 300), $bg);
      }
      ob_clean(); //without this the GD functions (like imagepng) tend to fail using CI
      header("Content-type: image/png");
      imagepng($im, NULL, 0, NULL);
      imagedestroy($im);
    }
    else{
      echo 'imagecreatefromstring() error.';
    }
  }
}
```

Put this file in the folder `root/application/controllers/`

Go to http://www.textbasedmafiagame.com/imagetest in your browser.

Comment: ran with: http://www.textbasedmafiagame.com/imagetest

still same . what could cause this?

Comment: Works on 2.1.4 both on a virtual WAMP stack and on a production server.

I'll experiment with your revised code on my virtual stack and see what happens.

Comment: @maria, Your update 2 code works for me. I had to use a slightly different routing  `$route['antibot/antibot_image'] = "antibot_interface_controller/getImage" ;`  Your route looks wrong to me but if you are getting to the right page (with or without loading the image) then it is obviously OK.

Comment: @maria, When you run the code from my answer you get only the 'broken image' placeholder?

Comment: that is correct @DFriend i run the code from your answer and get the broken image :/

Comment: i tried on newest CI, still the same issue somehow >.<

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92747/discussion-between-dfriend-and-maria).